# How can I forward user to android market to install an application

Tags: android

In my android application, how can I forward user to android market to install another application and after they install it, they come back to my activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start an Activity with Intent pointing to market:

```
String packageName = "com.stackoverflow.example";
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Replace `com.stackoverflow.example` with package name of target application.